# "permission denied"error even though I supposedly have full privipedge

Tags: macos, permissions

Here is the code

```
apple$ find . -name states.txt
find: ./Documents/Library: Permission denied
./Documents/states.txt
apples-MacBook-Pro:~ apple$ ls -la ./Documents/Library
ls: Library: Permission denied
apples-MacBook-Pro:~ apple$ sudo ls -la ./Documents/Library
Password:
total 0
drwx------@  3 root   staff   96 Mar  2  2021 .
drwx------@ 26 apple  staff  832 Oct 29 12:57 ..
drwx------   2 root   staff   64 Mar  2  2021 Logs
apples-MacBook-Pro:~ apple$
```

AS you can see, I should have rwx priviledges, yet Find still says permission denied for libraryfolder.why?

Comment: Presumably, you're running Big Sur or newer - you no longer have write permissions to anything at the root of the boot drive, not even if you disable SIP. The boot volume is not only locked, but secured by a cryptographic signature & hash. If you break that it will no longer boot. Instead it will offer only to re-install the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I do not see that in the output you provided. The *parent* directory `..` grants you rights; the Library directory itself `.` doesn't seem to.

According to the line for `.` (which represents the "Library" directory itself), that directory is owned by *root* and only grants rwx permissions to its owner (i.e. root) but not to anyone else. The same goes for the "Logs" subdirectory within.

To make it easier to see the permissions of just a directory on its own, use `ls -ld <path>`.

Comment: Hi, thank you again so much for your quick response. So would you please help me clarify a few things.Is it true that when I use -a option for ls, ls takes ./documents/library as the new working directory. So what print out as . meant the what was ./Documents/library rather than the actualy working directory?

Comment: Also, am I correct in understanding that I am apple, and I will be logged in as root if I use sudo command?

Comment: Apple doesn't use the concept of root in the same way as unix. Sudo gives you 'full admin' powers, similar but not identical to root. SIP will still prevent you doing anything to the protected system volume. Enabling & logging in as the actual root account [not recommended] will not gain you further powers.

Comment: But if I put sudo in front of find command, I no longer see all those annoying "permission denied" errors though. For example:sudo find . -name states.txt
Password:
./Documents/states.txt

Comment: Yeah, root can still bypass standard DAC permissions -- SIP works on a different level (aka "mandatory access control"), like SELinux or AppArmor would be on Linux. But there really is nothing unusual about root on macOS, it's the whole point of such security systems in general that root cannot directly bypass them, just like root can still be constrained by AppArmor or SMACK or SELinux etc.

Comment: And regarding `ls -a`, sort of, but it's _not quite_ "the new working directory" – the `.` actually has a slightly broader meaning than that. It's a virtual entry in **every** directory that means "the directory itself". For example, `Library/.` is the same thing as `Library` itself, and `./Documents/././Library` simply equals `Documents/Library` – it *does not* necessarily expand to the "current directory" the way ~/ expands to home.